# UIScrollView Does Not Work With Autolayout Programmatically(using more than one image)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

We are going to develop a project in ios, So that I am learning a auto layout with scrollview, It's working fine when I added one image, When I am trying to add more than one image, I got very strange thing the first image was stretched long and its overlapping with very next image. Here is my code

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

[scrollView addSubview:imageView1];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];

scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
 imageView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

self.imageViewPointer = imageView;
self.imageViewPointer = imageView1;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .5;
scrollView.delegate = self;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,imageView,imageView1);
NSLog(@"Current views dictionary: %@", viewsDictionary);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[imageView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-415-[imageView]|" options:0
                                                                   metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView1]-20-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView1]-150-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

and I got output!!!

[image]

Comment: It is working, but it is not that easy to setup the constraints. Here you have duplicate topic where a lot of people describes how they had dealt with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223021/i-am-officially-too-stupid-for-uiscrollview-with-autolayout

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use the PureLayout library: https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout

Comment: thanks for your response,Sorry I forgot to tell it"I am looking it in programmatically".

Comment: PureLayout is the way how to do it programatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of your scrollView's scrollable area will be set by the constraints of its subviews.

You have 2 constraints which can be used to specify the height of the scrollable area:

1. `"V:|-415-[imageView]|"`

   This tells Auto Layout to place your image 415 points from the top of its superview and to put it 0 points from the bottom of its superview.  It doesn't specify the height, but Auto Layout will use the height of the image contained in the imageView given no other constraints.  Note the imageView can be stretched if necessary to meet other constraints.
2. `"V:|[imageView1]-150-|"`

   This tells Auto Layout to place your image 0 points from the top of its superview and 150 points from the bottom of its superview.  It doesn't specify the height.  Because of this, Auto Layout is free to stretch one of the images to satisfy both constraints.

Instead, you should provide information on how the images are spaced relative to each other. For example:

`"V:|-20-[imageView1]-20-[imageView]-20-|"`

If you are adding these images one at a time, you don't have to specify this at one time.  You could add the constraints like this:

`"V:|-20-[imageView1]"`

"imageView1 is 20 points from the top of the superview"

`"V:[imageView1]-20-[imageView]"`

"imageView is 20 points below imageView1"

`"V:[imageView]-20-|"`

"imageView is 20 points from the bottom of the superview"

When you have constrained all of the image views to each other and to the top and bottom of the scrollView, Auto Layout will be able to calculate the height of the scrollView.

---

You are going to have a similar issue with your widths as well.  You have constrained both of your images to both sides of the superView:

`"H:|-20-[imageView]|"`
`"H:|[imageView1]-20-|"`

Because of that, Auto Layout will stretch one of your images to meet the constraints.  Only your widest image should be used to specify the width of the scrollView.  All of the others should only be constrained to the left edge of the superview and leave off the trailing `|`.

Again, if you are adding these images one by one and you don't know what the widest is until you've added them all, keep track of the widest one you've seen so far and only constrain the images to the left edge.  Then when you are done, add a constraint to set the width of your scroll area based upon the widest view:

`"H:|-20-[imageView]-20-|"`

Comment: yes now I got something about autolayout, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to have list of the images, you should use `UITableView`. But anyway, your code would look more like this:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-415-[imageView]" options:0
                                                                   metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView1]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView1]" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: I am doing it for learning basics in ios, I need to learn auto layout for ui components(like button,image,...).but I just tried it with image and I got the strange output. I need the reason why the first image was overlapped with second one. thanks for your response..

Comment: The layout is rendered in the way you wrote the code. Check the code (the AutoLayout constants).