# AutoLayout with ScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, scrollview

I have just joined iOS Develepors world.
i have a questions.

I don't understand auto layout with scrollview. Im tried every kind method but everytime seen different size and different location (button).

I just want to create scrollview (hortizonal) on 12 buttons for all IPhone models. What should i do? Could you write details.

Thank you so much.

Comment: i think you need to check this link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223021/i-am-officially-too-stupid-for-uiscrollview-with-autolayout....

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, you just have to be really methodic with all the constraints you add. I always start from the outside constraints and then start adding the inner ones.

Check out the tutorial I wrote for implementing a UIScrollView + Auto Layout in Swift. If you have any doubt, just ask me :)

https://www.dribba.com/blog/2015/07/21/scrollview-autolayout-ios8-swift/