# Swift - Visual constraints not working

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a scrollView which I instantiate programaticaly. What I want to do is to add constraints so it will look good in both horizontal and vertical orientation. The problem that constraints not working

How it looks vertically - good

[image]

How it looks horizontally - not good

[image]

Code is following

```
class FAPhoto: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var imageURLsArray = [String]()
var imageViews:[UIImageView] = []
var arrayOfPhotos = [Photo]()
var scrollView = UIScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(arrayOfPhotos.count), scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPhotos.count; i++) {
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * view.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        let image = imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: arrayOfPhotos[i].url!)!)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)


    }

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let bindings = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("scrollView", self.scrollView))

    let horizontalConstraints =
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: bindings)
    self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

    let verticalConstraints =
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: bindings)
    self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have warnings about broken constraints in the console?  As this is a scroll view... are you able to scroll around in either orientation?  If so, in which directions for each?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set `contentSize` of `scrollView` and imageView's frames in `viewDidLoad`. This is OK for portrait mode, but when view rotates to landscape, it's frame also changes, so you have to update these values accordingly. I think you have 3 opportunities here.

- Track rotation events and update `contentSize` of `scrollView` and imageView's frames, when view rotates.
- Use Autolayout for `scrollView`. You will not have to calculate `contentSize` or set imageView's frames, just set constraints once in `viewDidLoad`. Here you can find some examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/20232911/4757335.
- Use `UICollectionView` instead of `UIScrollView`. It handles rotation much easier.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I think I will try with first option. Can you advice, how can I change imageView's frames inside scrollView after they were created ?

Comment: In this case you will have to store references to imageViews in some array and then set their frames, just like you set them in viewDidLoad. Also I updated answer, and strongly recommend you to try third option.